# Android studio not opening Maven Integration Dialog

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, gradle, maven-plugin

Upgraded Android Studio to 1.3 and Maven Integration dialog is not opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question, because I was searching for this solution, found but difficult to understand, so I tried to show it graphically.

I used @Maher Answer and tried to show graphically

Step 1: In android studio Open **Tools** > **Android** > **Sdk Manager**

Step 2: Now click or **Plugin** > **Maven Integration** and mark **checked** and press **OK**. That's it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i tried this but it isnt working , any alternative solution for this?

Comment: it is working @N5 , I tried on several systems, whats your actual problem

Comment: same issue , but when i turn on the maven checkbox still that dialog box doesnt apper , i m on ubnutu .any idea?

Comment: umm, ohk, I was searching someone in my office having ubunto but did not found any, I think there is some other issue on your side, try to get latest update or just add the jars manually in gradle, do you know how to do this? if not then let me know I will guide you

Comment: :D i know , m not beginner , thx for suggestion i was just asking for `dialog issue not appearing`